# startService() и Firestore, повторный вызов onEvent()

Tags: android, firebase, service, firestore

Имеется сервис, который при запуске методом startService() начинает отслеживать изменения в БД Firestore. Все работает отлично, но при повторном вызове метода startService() (при повороте экрана или просто мануально, не важно) повторно срабатывает метод листенера onEvent.

Ниже в листинге метод initFirestore() вызывается из onStartCommand() сервиса:

```
private void initFirestore() {

    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query query = firestore.collection(FLIGHT_INFO_COLLECTION)
            .limit(20);

    query.addSnapshotListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

    if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {

        FlightInfoFirestoreModelDao flightInfoFirestoreModelDao = App.getInstance().getDatabase().flightInfoElementDao();
        FlightInfoFirestoreModel flightInfoItem;

        for (DocumentChange change : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            switch (change.getType()) {
                case ADDED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ADDED");
                    //Добавление данных в БД Room
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "REMOVED");
                    //Удаление данных из БД Room
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "MODIFIED");
                    //Обновление данных в БД Room
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Есть подозрение, что метод onEvent() не срабатывает, т.к. сервис не перезапускается повторным вызовом startService(), но я только начинаю работать с Firestore и не совсем понимаю логику это БД, почему происходит повторная запись данных в БД Room? Конечно можно указать проверку на наличие записей во избежание задвоения данных в БД Room, но меня интересует почему происходит повторное срабатываение метода листенера onEvent(), при этом метод onStartCommand() по логам не срабатывает.

ПС: срабатывает тип события в методе onEvent() именно ADDED, остальные события работают в штатном режиме.

Comment: upd. Возможно это связано с тем, что работа с БД Room идет не в отдельном потоке, как это должно быть по логике, но опять же это только догадки.

Comment: Оказалось все достаточно просто ... 
При вызове startService(...) происходит срабатывание метода onStartComand(...) каждый раз, а вот если служба запускается в первый раз, то срабатывает метод onCreate(...), далее onStartCommand(...). Одно не ясно для меня, почему в логах не отображались вызовы метода onStartCommand(...) при повторных вызовах метода startService(...)?